# Can I set a default value of Prometheus labels in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, prometheus

I'm using the official python (2.7) client.

I want to define a metric with some labels but I don't always have them all the labels to send. When I send only some of them I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute '_value'

This is the code I used:

```
c = Counter("counterTest, "explain this counter, labelnames=("label1", "label2",), namespace="namespace") 
c.labels(label1="1").inc(1)
```

Is this a limitation in the python library? Or maybe it's a limitation on the Prometheus end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must always specify all labels, how else would we know which series it is that you want to increment? You can specify an empty string as a label value, though this may cause confusion for your users.

Answer (score 4):

Global setting **Yes** (i.e. set only once at the time of Counter creation) -- but optionally Overridable later **No**.

i.e. I can set a label once at Counter init ... but I will NOT be able to override at actual inc call.

Set 'labelValues' when creating your Counter.

```
counter = Counter(
                name="some name", documentation="some doc",
                labelnames=['label1', 'label2', 'label3'], labelvalues=['label 1 global value])

counter.labels(label2='some value', label3='some value2').inc()
```

Comment: Might be a bit hacky since `labelvalues` has recently become a private member

Comment: Did you find a workaround?